# External HDD with one faulty unreadable folder

Tags: mount, usb-drive, external-hdd, testdisk

I did a mistake, probably unplugging my external usb drive during a write operation.

Now, the disk looks like it works fine, except **one** folder of the disk is shown empty.

```
phil@GLaDOS:/media/phil/Fumble$ ll
...
drwxrwxrwx  1 phil phil     4096 juil. 21  2018  Image/  #this folder is fine 
drwxrwxrwx  1 phil phil    45056 sept.  3 20:13  Video/  #this folder is not readable
...

phil@GLaDOS:/media/phil/Fumble$ ll Video/
ls: reading directory 'Video/': Input/output error
total 0
```

Looking at `dmesg` log

```
[21110.790593] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[21111.042432] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[21115.650384] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[21115.849157] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=61b7, bcdDevice= 0.00
[21115.849168] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[21115.849174] usb 1-7: Product: M3 Portable
[21115.849179] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: Seagate
[21115.849183] usb 1-7: SerialNumber: NM159VQ3
[21115.878600] scsi host9: uas
[21115.879668] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  M3 Portable      9300 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[21115.881748] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[21115.882182] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...
[21116.906347] ......ready
[21122.026701] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] 7814037167 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.64 TiB)
[21122.378320] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[21122.378330] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[21122.378704] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[21122.378843] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Preferred minimum I/O size 512 bytes
[21122.378848] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
[21122.483722]  sdc: sdc1
[21122.483916] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[21123.038776] usb 8-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 33 using xhci_hcd
[21132.414885] usb 8-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 33 using xhci_hcd
[21169.854807] usb 8-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 33 using xhci_hcd
[21241.437349] ntfs3: sdc1: volume is dirty and "force" flag is not set!
[21265.710869] usb 8-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 33 using xhci_hcd
[21265.728485] usb 8-2: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[21265.840116] usb 8-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 33 using xhci_hcd
[21266.292135] usb 8-2: USB disconnect, device number 33
[21266.420757] usb 8-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 34 using xhci_hcd
[21266.453600] usb 8-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0412, bcdDevice= 1.13
[21266.453608] usb 8-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[21266.453613] usb 8-2: Product: 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
[21266.453617] usb 8-2: Manufacturer: Generic
[21266.482078] hub 8-2:1.0: USB hub found
[21266.483436] hub 8-2:1.0: 2 ports detected
```

-->So `volume is dirty and "force" flag is not set` and `device descriptor read/8, error -71`

Using `testdisk`:

- "Undelete" option says `No deleted file found.`
- "List" option do find the folder and it's content, and subfolder content...

```
TestDisk 7.1, Data Recovery Utility, July 2019
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
https://www.cgsecurity.org
 1 P MS Data                     2048 7814035455 7814033408 [Fumble]
Directory /Video

>dr-xr-xr-x     0     0         0  3-Sep-2023 20:13 .
 dr-xr-xr-x     0     0         0 10-Jan-2023 10:38 ..
 dr-xr-xr-x     0     0         0 17-Feb-2022 17:56 MySubfolder1
 dr-xr-xr-x     0     0         0 10-Nov-2019 21:58 MySubfolder2
```

So file are here and seem fine. Now, why can't I access them normally, and what can I do to repair this?

Comment: It is an NTFS file system, which is a proprietary Microsoft file system. I think your best alternative is to use a dedicated Microsoft tool, `chkdsk /f`, or the graphical tool in Windows to repair it. - If you are lucky, it is enough to connect it to a Windows computer and unmount it (remove safely) before you shut down Windows. Otherwise use a dedicated Microsoft tool.) The beginning of [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072) will shed some light onto the problem (or at least a similar problem), Fast Startup in Windows.

Comment: Plugging it onto a windows computer then automatic repair did it. The hardest part was getting my hand onto a windows computer